# HTML table scollbar issue inside the div container

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am using the bootstrap for most CSS. I have divided a section into two columns, In left column showing a table with some data & on right side a Google map.The problem is that the table not showing scrollbar naturally when the table row grows. I have tried to control the scrollbar using the CSS but it is not working properly as you can see in the image.
[image]

There are two problems with scrollbar, first is far from the actual table & as per my guess it is because I am setting scrollbar on the parent `div` container. The second issue is that when I try to scroll it using the mouse wheel then the table starts flickering.I can't get my head around to solve this problem.
Here is my code.

**HTML Part**

*I have removed the irrelevant parts*

```
<main class="flex-shrink-0">
        <div class="container" style="max-width: 100% !important;">

            <section>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        
                        <div class="container" style="overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;;height:400px;width: 100%;">
                            <table class="" width="100%" style="overflow:auto; height: 400px;width: 100%;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Code</th>
                                        <th>Size</th>
                                        <th>Illumination Type</th>
                                        <th>Location</th>
                                        <th>Availability</th>
                                        <th>Media</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {% for hoarding in road_hoardings %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                                        <td>{{hoarding.site_code}}</td>
                                        <td>{{hoarding.size}}</td>
                                        <td>{{hoarding.illumination_type}}</td>
                                        <td>{{hoarding.location}}</td>
                                        <td>{{hoarding.available_by_date}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary">
                                                <i class="far fa-images"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>

        </div>
    </main>
```

**Table Related CSS**

```
body {
            /* overflow-x: hidden; */
            margin: 0;
            background: linear-gradient(45deg, #49a09d, #5f2c82);
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-weight: 100;
        }


        table {
            width: 800px;
            /* height: 400px; */
            /* border-collapse: collapse; */
            /* overflow: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto; */
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        th,
        td {
            padding: 15px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
            color: #fff;
        }

        th {
            text-align: left;
        }

        thead th {
            background-color: #55608f;
        }

        tbody tr:hover {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        }

        tbody td {
            position: relative;
        }

        tbody td:hover:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: -9999px;
            bottom: -9999px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
            z-index: -1;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added height and overflow in the container as well as table:

```
<div class="container" style="overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;;height:400px;width: 100%;">
    <table class="" width="100%" style="overflow:auto; height: 400px;width: 100%;">
```

You don't need to add overflow and height property in the table. Just keep it like this:

```
<table class="" width="100%" style="width: 100%;">
```

I have improved your code in below fiddle. Open it in full screen to see the best result.

```css
body {
            /* overflow-x: hidden; */
            margin: 0;
            background: linear-gradient(45deg, #49a09d, #5f2c82);
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-weight: 100;
        }


        table {
            width: 800px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        th,
        td {
            padding: 15px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
            color: #fff;
        }

        th {
            text-align: left;
        }

        thead th {
            background-color: #55608f;
        }

        tbody tr:hover {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        }

        tbody td {
            position: relative;
        }

        tbody td:hover:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: -9999px;
            bottom: -9999px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
            z-index: -1;
        }
```

```html
<main class="flex-shrink-0">
        <div class="container" style="max-width: 100% !important;">

            <section>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        
                        <div class="container" style="overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;;height:400px;width: 100%;">
                            <table class="" width="100%" style="width: 100%;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Code</th>
                                        <th>Size</th>
                                        <th>Illumination Type</th>
                                        <th>Location</th>
                                        <th>Availability</th>
                                        <th>Media</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>123</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>Type 1</td>
                                        <td>Location 1</td>
                                        <td>Date</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>

        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: ,Hey thanks for your response but the issue still persists.I still have the scrollbar on the div & the flicker issue is also there.

Comment: I have updated my answer. The problem was in table td{ position: relative; }. You must add overflow: hidden in this and the problem is gone.

Thanks me later.

Comment: Thanks a alot....The flickering issue is solved. But how can I solve that div scrollbar issue which is far from the table? How can I just add the scroll on the table instead of the div?